# Firebase - unable to nest a collection of collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

In my React Native project I am using Firestore as my database. Whenever a user registers I want to create a supervisor approval request.

Basically under a collection of `supervisorRequests` there should be a document for each `supervisor`, named after the supervisor's key. Under the supervisor document I want to have a collection of randomly generated ids which each hold the request metadata. Here is my desired structure:

```
-supervisorRequests
      -supervisor-1-Key
           -random-id-of-request
              - user: userID
              - userEmail: userEmail
              - requestDate: timestamp
           -random-id-of-request
              - user: userID
              - userEmail: userEmail
              - requestDate: timestamp
      -supervisor-2-Key
           -random-id-of-request
              - user: userID
              - userEmail: userEmail
              - requestDate: timestamp
           -random-id-of-request
              - user: userID
              - userEmail: userEmail
              - requestDate: timestamp
           -random-id-of-request
              - user: userID
              - userEmail: userEmail
              - requestDate: timestamp
```

My code trying to achieve this is:

```
const docReference = firebase.firestore().collection(`supervisorRequests`).doc(this.props.supervisorKey);
docReference.set({ user: this.props.userUID, requestDate: new Date().getTime(), userEmail: this.props.email });
```

My code, however, generates the following structure:

```
-supervisorRequests
      -supervisor-1-Key
          - user: userID
          - userEmail: userEmail
          - requestDate: timestamp
```

This is not what I want since every time a new request is made to the supervisor's key, the old request is overriden.

What would be wrong with my code and how can I achieve the first database structure I have presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you pass to collection() must be a path to a collection.  What you're passing now is the path to a document.  It discerns this by seeing the forward slash in the string.  Perhaps you want to reference the document like this instead:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection('supervisorRequests')
        .doc(this.props.supervisorKey)
```

You can use the returned DocumentReference to create the document with its set() method.

Comment: I just tried your code again. Your solution does not create a new node with random ID inside `this.props.supervisorKey`. It simply updates the old object with a new one. How can I add the object with a new random id?

Comment: As I said in the answer, the code returns a DocumentReference, which you then use to create the document with its set() method.

Comment: Either I am not doing what you are advising me to do correctly, or you have misunderstood my desired output. I have updated my question above with presenting what structure I would like and what my current code generates. Can you please have one more look? Thank you!

Comment: If you're trying to have collections immediately within other collections, that's not possible.  A subcolleciton must have a parent document id.

Comment: Oh, that's really unfortunate. Can you maybe advise me on how should I structure my data in this specific case then? What would be an optimal way of doing it?

Comment: The document where the subcollection is organized doesn't have to exist. It just needs to have a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete Doug's answer, note that you can directly pass a "slash-separated path" to the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#doc) method, in order to get "a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) instance that refers to the document at the specified path".

So you could also do:

```
firebase.firestore().doc(`supervisorRequests/${this.props.supervisorKey}`).set();
```